# LoadIncrementalHFiles increases used memory and fails after a while

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, bulk-load

I wrote about 300 directories containing HFiles into my HDFS (with a Spark application). They are saved to HDFS like this:

```
/user/testuser/data/hfiles_iteration_0/...
/user/testuser/data/hfiles_iteration_1/...
/user/testuser/data/hfiles_iteration_2/...
```

The files were created from ~15,000 CSV files with a total size of ~100 GB. I splitted the CSV files into bunchs and processed them iterative in my Spark application. However, now I need to process these 300 HFiles, to get the data added to my HBase table.

I created my HBase table via

```
create 'my_table', 
  {NAME => 'k', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'FAST_DIFF', COMPRESSION => 'SNAPPY'}, 
  {NAME => 'b', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'FAST_DIFF', COMPRESSION => 'SNAPPY'}, 
  {NAME => 't', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'FAST_DIFF', COMPRESSION => 'SNAPPY'}, 
  {SPLITS => [ '00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19']}
```

The data of the HFiles should already be partitioned by the 20 HBase region IDs 0 to 19.

Because I have to process one HFile directory after the other I created a Java application that also works iterative and runs the following command automatically:

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles -Dcreate.table=no <pathToReadFrom> my_table

//=> with <pathToReadFrom> = /user/testuser/data/hfiles_iteration_[0-299]
```

Here the whole logic as a code snippet:

```
TreeSet<String> subDirs = getHFileDirectories(new Path(HDFS_PATH), hadoopConf);

for(String hFileDir : subDirs) {

    try {
        String pathToReadFrom = HDFS_OUTPUT_PATH + "/" + hFileDir;
        String[] execCode = {"hbase", "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles", "-Dcreate.table=no", pathToReadFrom, hbaseTableName};
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(execCode);
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        final Process p = pb.start();

        // Write the output of the Process to the console
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                String line = null; 

                try {
                    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
                        System.out.println(line);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

    // Wait for the end of the execution
    p.waitFor();
    ...
}
```

The application works perfectly for the first ~200 of the ~300 HFile directories. But then further calls of `LoadIncrementalHFiles` fail with an exception.

**Can somebody help here? What am I doing wrong? Could there be some memory problems? Does each call need some "cool-down time" until the next iteration can start? I can't see a poblem with the code as >60 % of the iterations work well!**

Finally, here a screenshot of my host's memory usage, the Cache value started increasing when I started the application (in the screenshot it is still running):
[image]

Another observation: If one `LoadIncrementalHFiles` failed once, then all further iterations also fail. Restarting the job doesn't help. Also a restart of the Hadoop services or the complete nodes didn't help. I had to delete and re-create the HBase table via `hbase-shell` and then I was able to run the application again (till the same iteration as where the problem occured before)!

Other test: Here the outputs of the `lsof | wc -l` command, that shows the open files for my user - it increases very strong during execution:

```
// ***************************** Before execution *****************************

[user@hadoop ~]$ lsof | wc -l
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/42/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
14160

// ***************************** While execution ******************************

[user@hadoop ~]$ lsof | wc -l
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/42/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
99879

// ***************************** After execution ******************************

[user@hadoop ~]$ lsof | wc -l
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/42/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
14552
```

Thank you!

Comment: I guess it is the memory usage of the os.If so,can you share the snippet of the program where you are calling the org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles process.Inside the code,are you waiting for process to finish?

Comment: I added the code in my question. Yes, I'm running the command (each iteration) inside an own process and I'm waiting for finishing it in each iteration (process.waitFor). The cached memory increases on all Hadoop nodes, not only on the one where the program is running!

Comment: The amount of open files increases very strong during running the program, I also added these console output before / during / after execution.